# created an array of text randomly pick one to get displayed ,in this i want to allocate time for every item is this possible

Tags: php, arrays

using this scipt 
an array of text  randomly pick one to get displayed it's working fine

```
</head>

<body>
<?php function weightedRand($stream) {
    $pos = mt_rand(1,array_sum(array_keys($stream)));           
    $em = 0;
    foreach ($stream as $k => $v) {
        $em += $k;
        if ($em >= $pos)
            return $v;
    }

}

  $news = array(); //News Feed Array
    $news[] = '<a href="URL">Good morning!</a>';
    $news[] = '<a href="URL">have a nice day</a>';
    $news[] = 'work hard!';
    $news[] = '<a href="URL">experience makes man perfect.</a>';
    $news[] = '<a href="URL">hard work never fails</a>';



?>
<div id="example">
  <ul>
  <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
      echo '<li class="example">';
    echo weightedRand($news).'<br />';
    echo '</li>';
}?>

</ul>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#example').vTicker();

});
</script>
```

but here every text displayed 1min

I want i t changed so I want to  edit the percentage of the specific item. For example, I may want 'hard work never…' to be displayed 50% of the time. 
is this possible to do like this

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
$Expos['Google']['Science']='news.google.fr/news?topic=t';
$Expos['Google']['Economie']='news.google.fr/news?topic=b';
$Expos['Google']['Sante']='news.google.fr/news?topic=m';
$Expos['Yahoo']='fr.news.yahoo.com';
$Expos['Events']['LogicielLibre']='agendadulibre.org';
$Expos['MyBlog']='www.kik-it.com';

function array_multi_rand($Zoo){
    $Boo=array_rand($Zoo);
    if(is_array($Zoo[$Boo])){
        return array_multi_rand($Zoo[$Boo]);
    }else{
        return $Zoo[$Boo];
    }
}

echo(array_multi_rand($Expos));
```

Get more info on https://www.php.net/array_rand

Comment: above code am getting output fine but in that i have to  make time limit for ex-arr[1]--displays 1 min,arr[2]--display for 2min,arry[3]--display for 1min like this i need